# How does the @shopify/polaris project get built from github repo to npm dependency?

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I'm interested in learning how the [@shopify/polaris](https://github.com/Shopify/polaris) project in github is built and published to `npm`. My main questions are:

- How are the `index.es.js` and `index.js` files being generated? Are those being generated programmatically on my computer, or are they published to `npm` like this?
- What mechanism is preventing the files in the github repo from being downloaded when installed? I don't see a `.npmignore` in the repo.

Below I have the files in the `npm` package, and the github, and you can see they're different.

Here's what the `polaris` project looks like when it's installed via NPM / yarn.

```
.
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── README.md
├── index.es.js
├── index.js
├── package.json
├── src
├── styles
├── styles.css
├── styles.scss
└── types
```

Here's what the project looks like on github.

```
.
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── README.md
├── circle.yml
├── config
├── documentation
├── examples
├── package.json
├── scripts
├── src
├── tests
├── tsconfig.json
├── tslint.json
└── yarn.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

We use [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org) to generate the different entry files for Polaris. You can see our generic config file here: https://github.com/Shopify/polaris/blob/master/config/rollup/index.js. Note that it does all the work of compiling our TypeScript source files (using TypeScript and Babel), as well as kicking off the work required to bundle our CSS and icons as appropriate. This config generator is then run three times, which you can see here: https://github.com/Shopify/polaris/blob/master/scripts/build.js#L36-L38

1. The `main` entry file (`.js`, and spits out the CSS for our CDN)
2. The `module` entry file (`.es.js`)
3. The `embedded` entry file

We then copy these into their final locations for the NPM publish.

As for how we control what files are in the NPM package, we use the [`files` key](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) in our `package.json`; [these are the relevant lines](https://github.com/Shopify/polaris/blob/master/package.json#L107-L117).

Comment: What do you use to generate the Polaris website itself?

Comment: A whole pile of custom technologies, mostly built on React, GraphQL, and parsed markdown docs.